# xpages error message: unknown resource ID

Tags: xpages

How do I go about beginning to even trouble shoot this error message:

> [1920:000F-1C08] 25/03/2014 04:53:08 PM  HTTP JVM: !warn.DojoDependencyList.Internalerrorunknownresourceid0!

Background: xpages form developed in 8.5 and ran perfectly last year, now using the exact form again, but that error message appears in Domino server console when you load the page and when you attempt to submit it (it won't submit.)

The only thing obviously thing that has changed in the picture here in the past year is that the server has been upgraded to domino 9.02 fp 2.

Any ideas on how to even start pinning down what's up gratefully received, I'm sure it's something small and non-obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domino 9.0 uses Dojo 1.8 so my guess is there's an issue/conflict with your app and its use of Dojo.

Try forcing your app to use Dojo 1.6.1 by setting xsp.client.script.dojo.version to 1.6.1 in xsp.properties.

Comment: thanks Per Henrik, I suspect my trials aren't over yet, though.. that having been achieved (I documented how in the comments section here:)

[link]{http://www.intec.co.uk/domino-8-5-3-greater-power-over-dojo-thanks-ibm-for-your-work/}[/link]

I'm now onto what I suspect is next stage of the battle, 

No Dojo library found matching the configured Dojo library version xsp.client.script.dojo.version=1.6.1.

Comment: Works if you go for Dojo 1.5.1. Cheers, thanks! Hope this (and my linked instructions) can help others in the future.

Comment: Great to hear. Your next step is then to start looking into the way Dojo 1.8 works and use that moving forward :-)